# RCurl postForm fetching incorrect data

Tags: r, rcurl

I am trying to replicate the following in R

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"input":{"webpage/url":"http://http://www.mutualart.com/Exhibitions/Richard-Hamilton/4BC4569A3DCC902A"}}' "https://api.import.io/store/connector/13235010-2b34-4ddb-b8b7-245f12158424/_query?_user=63d1abec-6dde-4387-a5ac-75208005a0cb&_apikey=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

Under Linux, this works and I get the right output (page URL in the output matches `x`). But, in R, I get the incorrect output - I get the output for `http://www.mutualart.com/Exhibitions/Bailey-s-Stardust/14180718CB6BBBFF`

My R Code so far is

```
    x= list(items=c("http://www.mutualart.com/Exhibitions/Richard-Hamilton/4BC4569A3DCC902A"))

    headers <- list('Accept' = 'application/json', 'Content-Type' = 'application/json')

    uri <- "http://api.import.io/store/connector/13235010-2b34-4ddb-b8b7-245f12158424/_query?_user=63d1abec-6dde-4387-a5ac-75208005a0cb&_apikey=rhq3RoF9oXsoFLwPVfM%2Fkk7ephcJg0bqfbj51PPYhEbkITRm%2Fn23TvtJU4wVWfOkPBjL0sdhZTH5tZg%2Bom72iw%3D%3D"

    postForm(uri, .opts=list(postfields=toJSON(x), httpheader=headers))
```

Comment: Is that your actual API key?

Comment: Substantively, it doesn't look like your `toJSON(x)` operation will give you the appropriate json from your curl command you probably need something like `toJSON(list(input=list('webpage/url'=yourlongurl)))`. I assume that's the issue.